# HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Tags: java, android, timeout

В модуле задал таймер:

```
 @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClientBuilder(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor) {
       return new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // connect timeout
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
    }
```

Но ошибка все равно прилетает

Comment: Проблема может быть и на стороне сервера. Например у меня был случай, когда на сервере кончался пул соединений с БД из-за ошибки в логике сервера и соединения с клиента кончались ошибкой SocketTimeoutException

Comment: проблема оказалось в том , что нужно было постоянно в ретрофит билдер вешать окхттпклиент с таймаутом

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы имеете в виду) Может в ответ напишите как проблема решена была?